# "removeAttribute" not removing attributes

Tags: javascript, html, input, attributes

So, I'm making a chat website where you have to choose an username to be able to talk. By default, the input box to send messages is disabled (with the disabled attribute). I want my script to remove this attribute so that it becomes enabled ONLY when a user chosen a username. Now, I'm sure its a simple thing to fix but I really don't know a lot about JavaScript so that's quite difficult for me to find the problem.
Here is the code:

```js
      // Get references to the form elements
      const usernameForm = document.getElementById('username-form');
      const usernameInput = document.getElementById('username-input');
      const messageForm = document.getElementById('message-form');
      const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');
      const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-button');
      const chatWindow = document.getElementById('chat-window');
      
      let username = ''; // Store the chosen username
      
      // Handle the submit event for the username form
      usernameForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        // Prevent the form from refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // Get the value of the username input
        username = usernameInput.value;
        
        // Clear the input
        usernameInput.value = '';
        
        // Hide the username form and show the message form
        usernameForm.style.display = 'none';
        messageForm.style.display = 'flex';
      });
      
      // Handle the submit event for the message form
      messageForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        // Prevent the form from refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // Get the value of the message input
        const message = messageInput.value;
        
        // Clear the input
        messageInput.value = '';
        
        // Add the message to the chat window
        chatWindow.innerHTML += `<p><strong>${username}:</strong> ${message}</p>`;
        
        // Scroll the chat window to the bottom
        chatWindow.scrollTop = chatWindow.scrollHeight;

        // Check if the username has been set
        if (username === '') {
          // If the username has not been set, show an error message
          alert('You must choose a username before sending a message');
          return;
        }

        // Check if a username has been chosen
        if (username !== '') {
        // If a username has been chosen, remove the disabled attribute from the message input and send button
        messageInput.removeAttribute('disabled');
        sendButton.removeAttribute('disabled'); 
        }

      });
```

```css
      /* Add some basic styling for the chat window */
      #chat-window {
        width: 100%;
        height: 550px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      #message-form {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
      #message-input {
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin-right: 10px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      #send-button {
        height: 35px;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- Add a form for the user to enter their username -->
    <form id="username-form">
      <label for="username-input">Choose a username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username-input"/>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    
    <!-- Add a chat window to display the messages -->
    <div id="chat-window"></div>
    
    <!-- Add a form for the user to enter and send messages -->
    <form id="message-form">
      <input type="text" id="message-input" disabled/>
      <button type="submit" id="send-button" disabled>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

in the Java script and I also tried to find an alternative.

Comment: please post a working [repro] that also includes a minimal HTML to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Oh yea sorry, I've done it now

Answer (score 0):

You've simply attached the relevant event listener to the wrong form - to the "messageForm" rather than the "usernameForm". I've just made this one change below and now it seems to work as intended.

(Although you probably want to tidy it up as you now have two separate submit event handlers for that one form - there's nothing wrong with that but it's probably more readable when it's all inside a single handler function.)

```js
// Get references to the form elements
      const usernameForm = document.getElementById('username-form');
      const usernameInput = document.getElementById('username-input');
      const messageForm = document.getElementById('message-form');
      const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');
      const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-button');
      const chatWindow = document.getElementById('chat-window');
      
      let username = ''; // Store the chosen username
      
      // Handle the submit event for the username form
      usernameForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        // Prevent the form from refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // Get the value of the username input
        username = usernameInput.value;
        
        // Clear the input
        usernameInput.value = '';
        
        // Hide the username form and show the message form
        usernameForm.style.display = 'none';
        messageForm.style.display = 'flex';
      });

      // Handle the submit event for the message form
      usernameForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        // Prevent the form from refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get the value of the message input
        const message = messageInput.value;
        
        // Clear the input
        messageInput.value = '';
        
        // Add the message to the chat window
        chatWindow.innerHTML += `<p><strong>${username}:</strong> ${message}</p>`;
        
        // Scroll the chat window to the bottom
        chatWindow.scrollTop = chatWindow.scrollHeight;

        // Check if the username has been set
        if (username === '') {
          // If the username has not been set, show an error message
          alert('You must choose a username before sending a message');
          return;
        }

        // Check if a username has been chosen
        if (username !== '') {
        // If a username has been chosen, remove the disabled attribute from the message input and send button
        messageInput.removeAttribute('disabled');
        sendButton.removeAttribute('disabled'); 
        }

      });
```

```css
/* Add some basic styling for the chat window */
      #chat-window {
        width: 100%;
        height: 550px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      #message-form {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
      #message-input {
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin-right: 10px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      #send-button {
        height: 35px;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- Add a form for the user to enter their username -->
    <form id="username-form">
      <label for="username-input">Choose a username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username-input"/>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    
    <!-- Add a chat window to display the messages -->
    <div id="chat-window"></div>
    
    <!-- Add a form for the user to enter and send messages -->
    <form id="message-form">
      <input type="text" id="message-input" disabled/>
      <button type="submit" id="send-button" disabled>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works! The only thing I don't understand is that its sends the username text and it resets when you want to send text.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are referring to - but in any case it sounds like a new question, I showed you how to fix the one you were asking about here.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
messageInput.removeAttribute('disabled');
sendButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

You can use

```
messageInput.disabled = false;
sendButton.disabled = false;
```